# Standardizing dates in SQL. Arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a string field dob which has birthdates in various formats e.g.

dob

July 1, 1945
1967-1-7
13 May 1956

8 May 1947
27 September 1953
1952-3-25

I have attempted to use MS SQL 2005 to create a standardized date field

```
select convert(datetime,dob,103)
from myTable
```

I get an arithmetic overflow which appears to be associated with the last value, presumably because it is trying to convert the 25 to a month when it is a day 
I have tried 
    setting the language to british and various other styles without success

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you attempt to store it in a given format? Can you not just store it as a datetime type?  The biggest advantage to storing it in a locale independent is that you can offload the presentation logic to the UI where it belongs. Plus, you can avoid messy situations where you have a DOB of 3-4-5 (2003 April 5th, March 4th 2005, 3rd April 2005).

Conversion to a datetime works just fine for me (US locale).

```
; with myTable (dob)as
(
    select 'July 1, 1945'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1967-1-7'
    UNION ALL SELECT '13 May 1956'
    UNION ALL SELECT '8 may 1947'
    UNION ALL SELECT '27 september 1953'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1952-3-25'
)
SELECT
    cast(T.dob AS datetime) AS real_datetime
,   T.dob
FROM
    myTable T
```

Results

```
real_datetime   dob
1945-07-01 00:00:00.000 July 1, 1945
1967-01-07 00:00:00.000 1967-1-7
1956-05-13 00:00:00.000 13 May 1956
1947-05-08 00:00:00.000 8 may 1947
1953-09-27 00:00:00.000 27 september 1953
1952-03-25 00:00:00.000 1952-3-25
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was with the 103 style. However, I am still getting the same error when I apply it to the full table. single years only, nulls and blanks do not seem to be causing the problem. Is there anyway that SQL can identify the row(s) that are causing the error so that I can fix/exclude them

Comment: The easy-but-not-guaranteed-to-work solution is to add a where clause like `WHERE ISDATE(T.dob) > 0` Aaron Bertrand had a good explanation + approach on my similar [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/conversion-of-varchar-data-to-datetime-failing)

Comment: Thanks I had just arrived at same solution!

Comment: This way tou still have ambiguous dates, such as '11-05-2011' it will cast it as the default, it can be May 11 or Nov 05. Its a lot of trouble to have those dates stored like that

Comment: agreed. But I have no control over input